# How to avoid race condition on withdraw and deposit transactions in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, concurrency

I'm using Spring boot and JPA to develop a simple banking project and my question is that what is the best way to prevent race condition when deposit and withdraw method of an entity called at the same time.

I think I can solve it by using Lock Object and release it in each methods. However, I would like to see whether there is a cleaner way in spring boot.

Also I would like to know whether I should use @Transactional on both methods or not.

My classes are like below;

```
@Entity
public class Account implements Serializable{
    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7058816145650652977L;
    
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "ACCOUNTNUMBER")
private String accountNumber;

@Column(name = "OWNER")
private String owner;

@Column(name = "BALANCE")
private Double balance;
    ...

    public void deposit(Double amount) {
        balance += amount;
    }
    
    public void withdraw(Double amount) throws InsufficientBalanceException {
        if(balance < amount) {
            throw new InsufficientBalanceException();
        }
        balance -= amount;
    }
}
```

and my Account repository ;

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Account>{

    Optional<Account> findByAccountNumber(String accountNumber);
}
```

and finally here is my account service;

```
public interface AccountService {

    void deposit(String accountNumber, Double amount);
    void withdraw(String accountNumber, Double amount) throws InsufficientBalanceException;
}



@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public AccountServiceImpl(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void deposit(String accountNumber, Double amount) {
        Account account = accountRepository.findByAccountNumber(accountNumber).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
        account.deposit(amount);
    }

    @Override
    public void withdraw(String accountNumber, Double amount) throws InsufficientBalanceException {
        Account account = accountRepository.findByAccountNumber(accountNumber).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
        account.withdraw(amount);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, you need to lock the rows you want to update. JPA provides interface to lock rows which can prevents the rows from being updated or read.

LockModes

1. PESSIMISTIC_READ - shared lock, prevents update or delete
2. PESSIMISTIC_WRITE - exclusive lock, prevents read , update or delete
3. PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT

For you use case, PESSIMISTIC_WRITE can be used, but it can also hurt read performance as it will prevent read.
If you use hibernate Versioning, then you can also use PESSIMISTIC_READ, which does not prevent read.
For more information look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking).